# attaching Tooltip to item without fixed element 'id'

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to add tooltips to a Dojo application that I recently inherited. The problem I'm having is that everything is created with dojoAttachPoint identifiers instead of with id's , such as :

so, I can't use "connectId= " when defining the tooltip, until I get a hold of the element's id that I want to connect to. Basically my question is, how can I find the id based on the dojoAttachPoint?

Thanks much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The attach point is either going to be a domNode or a Widget based on whether it has a dojoType or not so if you have an attachPoint to a widgit then you can access connectid with this.myAttachWidget.connectid assuming that the attachPoint is in a widgets template.