# Attach Dojo Tooltip by Attribute or Class Instead of ID

Tags: javascript, dojo, tooltip

I have seen the answer here but I don't understand it [attaching Tooltip to item without fixed element 'id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772019/attaching-tooltip-to-item-without-fixed-element-id)

I am creating my Dojo Tooltips like this:

```
<script>
require(["dijit/Tooltip", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Tooltip){
    new Tooltip({
        connectId: ["div_1_1_2_1_1_1_2"],
        label: "Please select a Country, Subsidiary before selecting a City."
    });
    new Tooltip({
        connectId: ["div_1_1_2_1_2_1_2"],
        label: "Please select a Country, Subsidiary before selecting a City."
    });
});
</script>
```

My `div` IDs are generated, so I would rather bind tooltips to another variable, such as my attribute:

```
data-viewid="Date_Time_Picker2"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dojo/query` to find your nodes by attributes. Per the [dijit/Tooltip](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Tooltip.html) docs, connectId can be either ids or actual dom node references.

HTML:

```
<body class="claro">
    <div><span data-viewid="attachATooltipToMe">Test one</span>
    </div>
    <div> <span data-viewid="attachATooltipToMe">Test two</span>
    </div>
    <div> <span data-viewid="attachATooltipToMe">Test three</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
require(['dojo/query', 'dijit/Tooltip', 'dojo/domReady!'], function (query, Tooltip) {

    var nodes = query('[data-viewid="attachATooltipToMe"');

    new Tooltip({
        connectId: nodes,
        label: "Please select a Country, Subsidiary before selecting a City."
    });
});
```

This will attach tooltips to each node that has the data-viewid attribute specified with a value of "attachATooltipToMe".